# Selective Lazy Loading of child object in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, lazy-loading

I doubt this is possible but I will ask it anyway, just in case, is it possible to adapt lazyloading to only load child object who's 'IsDeleted' property is false?

This is just to help with the fact I need to add .where(x => !x.IsDeleted) to most of my methods, which is messy in my opinion.

**edit**

My entities are created using CodeFirst

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible if you use [conditional mapping](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/06/15/using-conditional-mapping-in-entity-framework.aspx). In such case EF will never load anything with `IsDeleted` set to true but in the same time `IsDeleted` column will not be available in your entity at all (because it will be used for mapping). If your application can also set this flag you will need to map stored procedures for entity - you can even map stored procedure for delete operation which will instead set the flag in the database instead of deleting the item.

Comment: Thanks, I should have said I am using CodeFirst as well

Comment: In such case the answer is no if you want to have easy access to `IsDeleted`.

Comment: lol, thanks, well I will have to stick to the code in the actionresults etc :)

Thanks